# \n in print statements in eval() functions not working

Tags: python, newline, eval

I am working on a project in python, and have encountered an error.

When I try to run this code: `eval("print(\"\n\")")`, it doesn't work and gives me an error: 'SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal'. But when I replace the '\n' with a 'Hello World', as shown in this code: `eval("print(\"Hello World\")")`, it prints the correct output.

Why is this? I would appreciate any thoughts on the issue so that I can continue working on my project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is seen as real newline (end of line, EOL) in the code processed by `eval`. Try `eval("print(\"\\n\")")`

Comment: Though on a different note: why are you using `eval`? If you're learning Python, that's one of the functions to stay far away from, no good code comes from using it.

Comment: @Mike *"no good code comes from using it"* -- There are niche cases, like [my answer on "Print self-documenting expression with value of variable on a new line"](/a/76335376/4518341). But yeah, best to stay away from it as a beginner.

Comment: No good code can come from eval. Only "this can be done better without eval" or "very clever code written by someone with a deep understanding of Python that is going to frustrate future maintainers" =)

Comment: I have tried to print `eval('print("\n")')` and get `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`, but `print("\n")` works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In `eval("print(\"\n\")")`, the backslash `\` before the `n` character is considered an escape character in Python strings hence it represents the newline character not the actual characters `\` and `n`

To fix this,

`eval("print(\"\\n\")")` - use a double backslash `\\`

Answer (score 0):

How eval() function works:

- Parse expression
- Compile it to bytecode
- Evaluate it as a Python expression
- Return the result of the evaluation

The `print()` expression will return `None`.

So if you would only a linbreak from `eval()`:

```
print('before')
eval(repr(print("\n")))
print('after')
```

Output:

```
before


after
```

This results the same as:

```
print('before')
print("\n")
print('after')
```